# Problems that will be covered outside the loop

Tags: python

```
def getDate():
    result = open('test1.html', 'r')
    data = re.findall(r"\"engine_jds\":(.+?),\"jobid_count\"",str(result.readlines()))
    jsonObj = json.loads(data[0])
    for item in jsonObj:
        var = item["company_name"], item["job_name"], item["workarea_text"], item[
            "providesalary_text"], item["companytype_text"], item["companysize_text"], item["jobwelf"]
        # print(var)
    print(var)
    # return var
```

Output in the loop can output all data without being overwritten, but output outside the loop will be overwritten and only the last data can be output.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you want *all* of the values that were assigned to `var` within the loop, you would need to append those values to a list (or other such container), and then return that list at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "overwritten" here, but you do have one major problem:

```
    ... str(result.readlines())
```

The `readlines` function returns a list of strings, one for each line.  The `str()` function will return a single string that looks like a Python list, with brackets and quotes:

```
"['Line one','Line two','Line three']"
```

You need to decide whether you want to handle the whole file at once (in which case you want `result.read()`), or if you want to handle the lines one by one, in which case you will need a loop.